# Using S3 bucket for SavedModel with tensorflow/serving:2.7.0-gpu Docker image

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, amazon-s3, tensorflow-serving

I'm trying to upgrade the Docker base image that we build on top of, for our TF-serving server. Currently, we use `tensorflow/serving:2.3.0-gpu` as the base image. I'm now trying out `tensorflow/serving:2.7.0-gpu`.

When I run the server with the exact same command as before, I get the following error:

`FileSystemStoragePathSource encountered a filesystem access error: Could not find base path s3://{s3_bucket}/{model_name}/ for servable {model_name} with error UNIMPLEMENTED: File system scheme 's3' not implemented (file: 's3://{s3_bucket}/{model_name}/')`

I want to mention again that the only thing I have changed is the TF-serving base image, and the same thing works with the earlier base image.

My model config file looks as follows:

```
model_config_list: {
  config: {
     name: "{model_name}",
     base_path: "s3://{s3_bucket}/{model_name}/",
     model_platform: "tensorflow",
     model_version_policy {
        specific {
            versions: {version}
        }
     }
  }
}
```

I understand that this error is because the TF I/O capabilities have been abstracted out into `tensorflow-io`. What is the recommended resolution for this? Is S3 no longer supported with TF-serving?

Comment: Can you take a look at [this comment](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/40302#issuecomment-748595980) and see if it helps? Also you can follow up [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/1963), which is already raised for the same in TF Serving repo.

Comment: Sorry, it does not, the link shared in the comment does not work anymore. I mentioned in the question about being aware of the issue being due to `tensorflow-io`, but this does not solve the underlying issue that the base Docker image does not support it. It leaves the installation part up to the user and is not enabled by default. I will add a link to the question on the issue you mentioned.